# Difference between "bizarre" and "eccentric"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

In google translate, the word "bizarre" means "very strange or unusual, especially so as to cause interest or amusement.". But I believe that this description is more suited for "eccentric". For example, the character of Jack Sparrow from Pirates of the Caribbean is eccentric.

On the other hand, AI chat GPT says that "bizarre" usually means something odd and unsettling. And I have seen people make use of the word "bizarre" for criticizing something, rather than an expression of fascination.

In Meriam-Webster site, "bizarre" means
odd or eccentric in stye.

This means "bizarre" and "eccentric" share the same meaning?

But "Jack Sparrow is such a bizarre person" and "Jack Sparrow is such an eccentric person" don't seem to resonate. I got different vibes from them. Or is it just my feeling?

Both means "unconventional"?

What are their subtle differences, and can I have one example for each that would enlighten me about their differences?

Comment: Did you check an actual _dictionary_?

Comment: @Heartspring Yes, from Meriam-Webster, see my edit.

Comment: @Heartspring they seem to share meaning, but I have made another edit. Two words seem to give different vibes.

Comment: Bizarre is a negative. Eccentric may be good (charming) or bad (wacko) depending on your vantage point. People can be eccentric, actions bizarre.

Comment: People are eccentric, things are bizarre.

Comment: @YosefBaskin how about bizarre dresses and hairstyles? In a fashion show. That is not negative. It is an example from Google translate.

Comment: Yes, bizarre dresses and hairstyles are criticisms of those items.

Answer (score 3):

Although the two words are arguably synonyms (in their prototypical senses as adjectives):

> *bizarre* a: odd, extravagant, or eccentric in style or mode ...
>
> *a bizarre outfit*

there is a hint of or even arguably requirement for the outlandish with 'bizarre':

> *bizarre*  b: involving sensational contrasts or incongruities

[both entries from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bizarre).

Probably correspondingly, 'eccentric' is applied to persons more often than 'bizarre' is. It conveys more acceptability of the odd trait:

> *eccentric* [adjective] 1:
>
> [of a person or their behaviour]: unconventional and slightly strange.

[[Oxford Languages; via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=eccentric+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&biw=1344&bih=782&ei=DfBYZPXTNoiA8gKD1o-wAQ&ved=0ahUKEwi1jsCn4eX-AhUIgFwKHQPrAxYQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=eccentric+meaning&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIPCAAQigUQsQMQQxBGEPkBMgcIABCKBRBDMgcIABCKBRBDMgcIABCKBRBDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgoIABBHENYEELADOgoIABCKBRCwAxBDOgwIABCKBRBDEEYQ-QE6CggAEIAEELEDEApKBAhBGABQmQZYuhZgxhloAXAAeACAAU6IAc8DkgEBN5gBAKABAcgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]

> *eccentric* 1a: deviating from conventional or accepted usage or conduct especially in odd or whimsical ways
>
> *an eccentric millionaire*

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eccentric)]

Examples where I'd argue one synonym works much better than the other:

- *It is a bizarre tale and the author hits just the right note of horror and disbelief.* [[ExamWord](https://www.examword.com/sentence/word?x=bizarre)]
- *The plot of the novel was too bizarre to be believed.* [[ExamWord](https://www.examword.com/sentence/word?x=bizarre)]
- *You know, that book you lent me is really bizarre.* [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/bizarre)]
- *You also worked with another eccentric genius.* [[Your Dictionary](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/eccentric)]
- *He is an eccentric character who likes wearing a beret and dark glasses.* [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/eccentric)]
- *The only solution would be to counterbalance this negativity in my own eccentric little way.* [[Sunday Times (2016)_Collins Corpus](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/eccentric)]
- *His eccentric character and honesty appeals to many.* [[The Sun (2016)_Collins Corpus](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/eccentric)]
- *We can become eccentric and nobody minds, which is a great freedom.* [[Sunday Times (2009)_Collins Corpus](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/eccentric)]

An example where either works, but with the 'outlandish' thrust if 'bizarre' is chosen:

- *The game was also notable for the bizarre behaviour of the team's manager.*